# Enviar más de una imagen por post

Tags: c#, post, trello

Tengo un código para crear tarjetas de trello por medio de c#, puedo crear la tarjeta y enviarle una imagen, pero no sé cómo enviar más de una imagen para una misma tarjeta, alguien que me pueda dar una guía?

```
    public byte[] File { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }

    public FormUpload(byte[] file, string filename, string contenttype)
    {
        File = file;
        FileName = filename;
        ContentType = contenttype;
    }
    private static readonly Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    //primer metodo
    public static HttpWebResponse MultipartFormPost(string postUrl, string userAgent, Dictionary<string, object> postParameters, string headerkey, string headervalue)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        //var fileName = "C:\\Users\\usuario\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Snapshot_81689ad276524d5.jpg";
        var fileName = "D:\\SEGESCOT\\Sintítulo.png";
       // var fileName = "https://cflvdg.avoz.es/sc/uo6Kh0onO3js1onHHNrRLV7X-Os=/x/2019/02/26/00121551208683005769902/Foto/HF27C11F1_201630.jpg";
        postUrl = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards";
        string formDataBoundary = String.Format("----------{0:N}", Guid.NewGuid());
        string contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + formDataBoundary;
        postParameters.Add("name", "prueba");
        postParameters.Add("desc", "prueba");
        postParameters.Add("idList", "prueba");
        postParameters.Add("keepFromSource", "all");
        postParameters.Add("key", "prueba");
        postParameters.Add("token", "prueba");
        byte[] bytes = wc.DownloadData(fileName); // You need to do this download if your file is on any other server otherwise you can convert that file directly to bytes 
        postParameters.Add("fileSource", new FormUpload(bytes, Path.GetFileName(fileName), "image/png"));
        byte[] formData = GetMultipartFormData(postParameters, formDataBoundary);

        return PostForm(postUrl, userAgent, contentType, formData, headerkey, headervalue);
    }

    //Armar request
    private static byte[] GetMultipartFormData(Dictionary<string, object> postParameters, string boundary)
    {
        Stream formDataStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        bool needsCLRF = false;

        foreach (var param in postParameters)
        {

            if (needsCLRF)
                formDataStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes("\r\n"), 0, encoding.GetByteCount("\r\n"));

            needsCLRF = true;

            if (param.Value is FormUpload) // to check if parameter if of file type   
            {
                FormUpload fileToUpload = (FormUpload)param.Value;

                // Add just the first part of this param, since we will write the file data directly to the Stream  
                string header = string.Format("--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{1}\"; filename=\"{2}\"\r\nContent-Type: {3}\r\n\r\n",
                    boundary,
                    param.Key,
                    fileToUpload.FileName ?? param.Key,
                    fileToUpload.ContentType ?? "application/octet-stream");

                formDataStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes(header), 0, encoding.GetByteCount(header));

                // Write the file data directly to the Stream, rather than serializing it to a string.  
                formDataStream.Write(fileToUpload.File, 0, fileToUpload.File.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                string postData = string.Format("--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{1}\"\r\n\r\n{2}",
                    boundary,
                    param.Key,
                    param.Value);
                formDataStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes(postData), 0, encoding.GetByteCount(postData));
            }
        }

        // Add the end of the request.  Start with a newline  
        string footer = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n";
        formDataStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes(footer), 0, encoding.GetByteCount(footer));

        // Dump the Stream into a byte[]  
        formDataStream.Position = 0;
        byte[] formData = new byte[formDataStream.Length];
        formDataStream.Read(formData, 0, formData.Length);
        formDataStream.Close();

        return formData;
    }

    //Hacer el request
    private static HttpWebResponse PostForm(string postUrl, string userAgent, string contentType, byte[] formData, string headerkey, string headervalue)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(postUrl) as HttpWebRequest;

        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("request is not a http request");
        }

        // Set up the request properties.  
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = contentType;
        request.UserAgent = userAgent;
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.ContentLength = formData.Length;

        // You could add authentication here as well if needed:  
        // request.PreAuthenticate = true;  
        // request.AuthenticationLevel = System.Net.Security.AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequested;  

        //Add header if needed  
        request.Headers.Add("key", "13b23b1c614accbf488a4540f4e87b33");

        // Send the form data to the request.  
        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(formData, 0, formData.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
        }

        return request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    }
}
```

En este caso le entra un array de imagenes pero no sé como recorrer e insertar las imagenes una por una, alguien que me ayude por favor

En este caso le entra un array de imagenes pero no sé como recorrer e insertar las imagenes una por una, alguien que me ayude por favor

En este caso le entra un array de imagenes pero no sé como recorrer e insertar las imagenes una por una, alguien que me ayude por favor

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el código con el que creas la tarjeta y le envías la imagen para poder analizarlo?

Comment: Hecho @CarlosAlbertoMarrufo